# std::chrono::duration integer difficulties

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I have this simple template stopwatch timer which I'm planning to use in my next project, whenever I instantiate this class using "Timer< float >" everything works fine, however if I use "Timer< int >" I get errors.

> timer.h(18): error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>' to 'std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>'

I am clueless why this happens, all help appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
template< typename type > class Timer
{

public:

    void Start(){ m_Start = m_Time.now(); }
    void Reset(){ m_Start = m_Time.now(); m_Split = m_Start; }
    void Split(){ m_Split = m_Time.now(); }

    type HoursSinceStart()          { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::ratio< 3600 > >( m_Time.now() - m_Start ).count(); }
    type MinutesSinceStart()        { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::ratio< 60 > >( m_Time.now() - m_Start ).count(); }
    type SecondsSinceStart()        { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::ratio< 1 > >( m_Time.now() - m_Start ).count(); }
    type MilliSecondsSinceStart()   { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::milli >( m_Time.now() - m_Start ).count(); }
    type MicroSecondsSinceStart()   { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::micro >( m_Time.now() - m_Start ).count(); }
    type NanoSecondsSinceStart()    { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::nano >( m_Time.now() - m_Start ).count(); }

    type HoursSinceSplit()          { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::ratio< 3600 > >( m_Time.now() - m_Split ).count(); }
    type MinutesSinceSplit()        { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::ratio< 60 > >( m_Time.now() - m_Split ).count(); }
    type SecondsSinceSplit()        { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::ratio< 1 > >( m_Time.now() - m_Split ).count(); }
    type MilliSecondsSinceSplit()   { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::milli >( m_Time.now() - m_Split ).count(); }
    type MicroSecondsSinceSplit()   { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::micro >( m_Time.now() - m_Split ).count(); }
    type NanoSecondsSinceSplit()    { return std::chrono::duration< type, std::nano >( m_Time.now() - m_Split ).count(); }

private:

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock m_Time;

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_Start;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_Split;
};
```

Comment: `std::chrono` already defines `hours minutes seconds` etc. you don't need to define them yourself.

Comment: Thanks I've changed my code, it now uses std::chrono::<durationtype> on all functions for readability !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chrono` library is trying to save you from accidentally loosing information during a units conversion.  For example, it is always ok to convert `minutes` to `nanoseconds`, because `nanoseconds` can always exactly represent any number of `minutes`.

But `nanoseconds` won't so easily convert to `minutes` because this conversion is "lossy".  The conversion won't be exact, it will have truncation (roundoff) error.  If you really want such a conversion, you have to be explicit about it.  This is what `std::chrono::duration_cast` is for.  For example:

```
minutes m = duration_cast<minutes>(ns);
```

This says to convert `nanoseconds` to `minutes`, and truncate towards zero when you have some left over `nanoseconds`.

This "safety net" is only applicable to integral representations (e.g. `int`).  When you use floating-point based durations, an implicit conversion from `nanoseconds` to `minutes` is allowed because the floating point type will represent fractions of a `minute` coming from left over `nanoseconds`.

In case you need rounding modes other than "truncate towards zero", [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html) are some utilities to do so.